# $F_k|F_n$ given $k | n$

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

**Problem:** Given $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k | n$, show that $F_k|F_n$.

**My attempt:** We have that $F_n = |\tau_{n-1}|$ where $|\tau_{n-1}|$ represents the number of ways to tile a row of $n-1$ squares using dominos(which can cover two squares) and monominos(which can cover one square). Similarly, $F_k = |\tau_{k-1}|$. Then since $k|n$, we have that $n = ak$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$. So $$|\tau_{n-1}| = |\tau_{k-1}|\cdot|\tau_{n-k}| = |\tau_{k-1}|\cdot |\tau_{(a-1)k}| = |\tau_{k-1}|\cdot|\tau_k|^{a-1},$$
where the last equality is obtained from the product rule. Then this shows that $|\tau_{k-1}|$ divides $|\tau_{n-1}|$, and so $F_k$ divides $F_n$.

**Question:** Is this approach correct or did I make a mistake somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: How do you get $|\tau_{n-1}| = |\tau_{k-1}|\cdot|\tau_{n-k}|$?  This suggests that you'll always tile the first $k-1$ squares, but why can't you tile the first $k-2$ squares and then place a domino?

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I misunderstood how the product rule works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You are getting close! Your formula for $\tau_{n-1}$ is incorrect, since it does not account for tilings where a domino covers squares numbered $k-1$ and $k$. So, how many of those tilings did you miss? Adding in the number of missing tilings gives the correct formula:
$$
\tau_{n-1}=\tau_{k-1}\tau_{n-k}+\underline{\hspace{2cm}}
$$
and you can use the corrected formula to prove that $F_{n}$ is a multiple of $F_{k}$.

Further hint, if you need it:

> Start with the special case $n=2k$, then $n=3k$, until the pattern of the proof is clear.